# oracle Select dates for items sold within 1 minute of each other

Tags: sql, oracle, date, seconds, listagg

Oracle 12c database.

I have a car sales table:

```
CREATE TABLE CAR_SALES 
   (    NUM_CARS NUMBER(10,0), 
    EQUIPMENT_TYPE VARCHAR2(100), 
    LOCATION VARCHAR2(500), 
    SOLD_DATE DATE
   ) ;

--Insert sample data

insert into car_sales (num_cars,equipment_type,location,sold_date) values ('8','Rovers','coventry','07-SEP-19 10:00:12');

insert into car_sales (num_cars,equipment_type,location,sold_date) values ('1','Rovers','coventry','07-SEP-19 10:00:45');

insert into car_sales (num_cars,equipment_type,location,sold_date) values ('9','Jaguars','coventry','07-SEP-19 06:00:00');

insert into car_sales (num_cars,equipment_type,location,sold_date) values ('7','Rovers','leamington','30-AUG-19 13:10:13');

insert into car_sales (num_cars,equipment_type,location,sold_date) values ('10','Trans Am','leamington','30-AUG-19 09:00:00');

insert into car_sales (num_cars,equipment_type,location,sold_date) values ('2','Trans Am','leamington','30-AUG-19 13:10:48');

insert into car_sales (num_cars,equipment_type,location,sold_date) values ('8','Rovers','coventry','06-SEP-19 18:00:00');

insert into car_sales (num_cars,equipment_type,location,sold_date) values ('4','Rovers','leamington','06-SEP-19 09:00:00');

insert into car_sales (num_cars,equipment_type,location,sold_date) values ('100','Trans Am','leamington','06-SEP-19 08:59:45');

insert into car_sales (num_cars,equipment_type,location,sold_date) values ('1','corvette','leamington','06-SEP-19 09:00:10');

insert into car_sales (num_cars,equipment_type,location,sold_date) values ('2','Toyota','coventry','06-SEP-19 10:00:00');

insert into car_sales (num_cars,equipment_type,location,sold_date) values ('15','Rovers','coventry','07-SEP-19 11:05:00');

insert into car_sales (num_cars,equipment_type,location,sold_date) values ('2','Jaguars','coventry','07-SEP-19 17:02:07');

insert into car_sales (num_cars,equipment_type,location,sold_date) values ('3','Trans Am','leamington','30-AUG-19 13:10:25');

commit;
```

I need to select only the sales (dates of sales) that have occurred within 1 minute by a location.

I have created the following sql example, but it is not displaying only the records that share a sales date within 1 minute for a location, it is showing all the records for a location.  Also, is it possible to create a listagg of the result set by location|equipment_type for matching dates within 1 minute?  I don't know how I would get the results then have those results display like:

For the records that are within 1 minute:

```
coventry  07-SEP-19 10:00:45 Rovers
coventry  07-SEP-19 10:00:12 Rovers
```

Listagg would be:

```
LOCATION listagg(EQUIPMENT_TYPE)

coventry Rovers,Rovers
```

-- the equipment_type in this example just happens to be rover,rover, it would be whatever equipment_type is joined by the matching 1 minute sales.

```
SQL>
select location,sold_date,equipment_type,num_cars
from car_sales c
where exists( select 'X' 
                from car_sales x
                  where c.location=x.location
                  and c.equipment_type=x.equipment_type
                  and c.sold_date between x.sold_date - interval '1' MINUTE
                  and x.sold_date + interval '1' MINUTE
                  )
                  group by location,sold_date,equipment_type,num_cars
                  order by sold_date desc;
```

How could I create the correct results and make a listagg of the results of equipment_types by location that have sales within 60 seconds.

Thank you in advance.
Gilly

Comment: Just a side observation - it is good that you made SOLD_DATE a DATE datatype.  That's as it should be. But then you are inserting a character string, forcing oracle to perform an implied TO_DATE in order to convert it into oracle's internal, binary format for a DATE.  Perhaps you got lucky that NLS_DATE_FORMAT matched, but you shouldn't depend on luck. Also, you should _always_ specify 4-digit years. Your INSERT should be: insert into car_sales (num_cars,equipment_type,location,sold_date) values ('8','Rovers','coventry',to_date('07-SEP-2019 10:00:12',dd-MON-yyyy hh24:mi:ss');

Comment: thank you for the advice Ed, I agree about the year YYYY. :-)

Comment: What results do you want in case of 10:00:00, 10:00:30,10:01:00,10:01:30? Do you want to aggregate all of them?

Comment: Or it should be aggregated by trunc(date, 'mi'), ie by minute: 2 in 10:00:00 and others 2 - 10:01:00

Comment: Thank you Sayan for your comment. For a location the results should only be those who are dates within 60 seconds of all results, only the ones with the 60 tie together are the results...I know it is hard to code.

Comment: @Gilly but look at this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7468e2634dd80a6de230c9d363d944ad

Comment: @Gilly as you can see it aggregates all 10:00:12,10:00:45,10:01:15,10:01:30 into the same group. Is it really what you need?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov `10:00:12` and `10:00:45` are within a minute of each other and should be in the same group and `10:00:45` and `10:01:15` are within a minute of each other too. You can either: have all 3 in the same group (even though the highest and lowest are not within a minute of each other); or, duplicate rows so the the middle value can be in 2 groups; or have a method to pick only certain values for a group while excluding other potential groupings (such as grouping within the same minute past the hour). Any of those are potentially valid solutions.

Comment: @MT0 yeah, I know, but I want to know what exactly Gilly needs

Comment: I've added one of the possible solutions with non-overlapping intervals lessa than a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LAG`/`LEAD` analytic functions to compare the previous and next rows to determine if they are within a minute of the current row:

```sql
SELECT location,
       LISTAGG( equipment_type, ',' )
         WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY sold_date )
         AS equipment_types,
       LISTAGG( TO_CHAR( sold_date, 'HH24:MI:SS' ), ',' )
         WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY sold_date )
         AS sold_dates
FROM   (
  SELECT num_cars,
         equipment_type,
         location,
         sold_date,
         CASE
         WHEN within_minute_of_prev = 1 OR within_minute_of_next = 1
         THEN SUM(
                CASE
                WHEN within_minute_of_prev = 0 AND within_minute_of_next = 1
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END
              ) OVER ( PARTITION BY location ORDER BY sold_date )
         END AS grp
  FROM   (
    SELECT c.*,
           CASE
           WHEN ( sold_date
                  - LAG( sold_date ) OVER ( PARTITION BY location ORDER BY sold_date )
                ) DAY TO SECOND
                <= INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END AS within_minute_of_prev,
           CASE
           WHEN ( LEAD( sold_date ) OVER ( PARTITION BY location ORDER BY sold_date )
                  - sold_date
                ) DAY TO SECOND
                <= INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END AS within_minute_of_next
    FROM   car_sales c
  )
)
WHERE grp IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY location, grp;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CAR_SALES ( NUM_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, SOLD_DATE ) AS
  SELECT   8, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:00:12' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   1, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:00:45' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   9, 'Jaguars',  'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '06:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   7, 'Rovers',   'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '13:10:13' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  10, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '09:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '13:10:48' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   8, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '18:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   4, 'Rovers',   'leamington', DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '09:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 100, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '08:59:45' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   1, 'corvette', 'leamington', DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '09:00:10' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Toyota',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '10:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  15, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '11:05:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Jaguars',  'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '17:02:07' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '13:10:25' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> LOCATION   | EQUIPMENT_TYPES          | SOLD_DATES                
> :--------- | :----------------------- | :-------------------------
> coventry   | Rovers,Rovers            | 10:00:12,10:00:45         
> leamington | Rovers,Trans Am,Trans Am | 13:10:13,13:10:25,13:10:48
> leamington | Trans Am,Rovers,corvette | 08:59:45,09:00:00,09:00:10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=85c7924383f5b36d59996c1c626f0747)*

---

## Update

A much shorter Oracle 12c query uses `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT location,
       LISTAGG( equipment_type, ',' )
         WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY sold_date )
         AS equipment_types,
       LISTAGG( TO_CHAR( sold_date, 'HH24:MI:SS' ), ',' )
         WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY sold_date )
         AS sold_times
FROM   car_sales
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
   PARTITION BY location
   ORDER BY sold_date
   MEASURES  
      MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno
   ALL ROWS PER MATCH
   PATTERN (A B+)
   DEFINE
      B AS B.sold_date <= PREV(B.sold_date) + interval '1' minute
)
GROUP BY location, mno
ORDER BY location, mno;
```

Which, for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CAR_SALES ( NUM_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, SOLD_DATE ) AS
  SELECT   8, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:00:12' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   1, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:00:45' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:01:15' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:01:30' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   9, 'Jaguars',  'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '06:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   7, 'Rovers',   'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '13:10:13' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  10, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '09:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '13:10:48' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   8, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '18:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   4, 'Rovers',   'leamington', DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '09:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 100, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '08:59:45' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   1, 'corvette', 'leamington', DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '09:00:10' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Toyota',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '10:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  15, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '11:05:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Jaguars',  'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '17:02:07' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '13:10:25' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> LOCATION   | EQUIPMENT_TYPES             | SOLD_TIMES                         
> :--------- | :-------------------------- | :----------------------------------
> coventry   | Rovers,Rovers,Rovers,Rovers | 10:00:12,10:00:45,10:01:15,10:01:30
> leamington | Rovers,Trans Am,Trans Am    | 13:10:13,13:10:25,13:10:48         
> leamington | Trans Am,Rovers,corvette    | 08:59:45,09:00:00,09:00:10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eb4e89aa4f79d778594c838fb7632bfc)*

Comment: MTO: WOW, you have it!  I am very, very impressed.  Thank you, I considered LAG but could not get it to work.

Comment: What if we had the time value `10:01:13` also for september 7th,2019, how can it be grouped ? (nevertheless such a nice solution )

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Successive time gaps smaller than a minute will be included in the same group; so you may find that the smallest and largest values in a group have an interval greater than a minute between them but there will always be a chain of time gaps less than a minute. The OP needs to pick how they are gouping but it is almost impossible to have groups where all values are within a minute of each other and to not exclude other potential values from the group without introducing duplicates so that one value can be in multiple groups.

Comment: Why did you copy my answer even without the link to my answer?

Comment: Moreover you haven't even showed that this is not just "shorter" version, that is different algorithm with different results

Comment: The results are only different because the first one has only the OP's data and the second one has the same data with 2 added rows (that were discussed in comments on the OP's question) other than that the original and updated algorithms are the same.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't got an answer how should be aggregated a chain of several rows where each of them is less than a minute before previous one, for example

```
  SELECT   1, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:00:12' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:00:45' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:01:15' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:01:30' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL
```

Since you have already a solution which aggregates all such values into one group(ie 10:01:30-10:00:12 > 1 minute, but they are still in the same group), I'll show how to get groups where the maximum difference between first and last sales <= 1 minute.

In this case it's better to use analytic functions with `range between current row and interval '1' minute following`. For example, for each sale we can easily get how many sales we have in the same location in next minute:

```sql
with CAR_SALES ( NUM_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, SOLD_DATE ) AS (
  SELECT   1, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:00:12' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:00:45' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:01:15' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:01:30' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   9, 'Jaguars',  'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '06:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   7, 'Rovers',   'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '13:10:13' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  10, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '09:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '13:10:48' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   8, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '18:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   4, 'Rovers',   'leamington', DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '09:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 100, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '08:59:45' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   1, 'corvette', 'leamington', DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '09:00:10' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Toyota',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '10:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  15, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '11:05:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Jaguars',  'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '17:02:07' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '13:10:25' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL
)
SELECT 
   location,
   num_cars,
   equipment_type, 
   sold_date,
   count(*)over(partition by LOCATION order by SOLD_DATE range between current row and interval'1' minute following) cnt
from car_sales
order by location,sold_date;
```

I've added a couple additional rows to make it easier to see the difference.
Results:

```sql
LOCATION     NUM_CARS EQUIPMEN SOLD_DATE                  CNT
---------- ---------- -------- ------------------- ----------
coventry            2 Toyota   2019-09-06 10:00:00          1
coventry            8 Rovers   2019-09-06 18:00:00          1
coventry            9 Jaguars  2019-09-07 06:00:00          1
coventry            1 Rovers   2019-09-07 10:00:12          2
coventry            2 Rovers   2019-09-07 10:00:45          3
coventry            3 Rovers   2019-09-07 10:01:15          2
coventry            3 Rovers   2019-09-07 10:01:30          1
coventry           15 Rovers   2019-09-07 11:05:00          1
coventry            2 Jaguars  2019-09-07 17:02:07          1
leamington         10 Trans Am 2019-08-30 09:00:00          1
leamington          7 Rovers   2019-08-30 13:10:13          3
leamington          3 Trans Am 2019-08-30 13:10:25          2
leamington          2 Trans Am 2019-08-30 13:10:48          1
leamington        100 Trans Am 2019-09-06 08:59:45          3
leamington          4 Rovers   2019-09-06 09:00:00          2
leamington          1 corvette 2019-09-06 09:00:10          1

16 rows selected.
```

Moreover, we can easily check also preceding rows and filter only those rows which have cnt_preceding>1 or cnt_following>1, ie rows which have neighbors <= 1 minute:

```sql
select *
from (
   SELECT 
      location,
      num_cars,
      equipment_type, 
      sold_date,
      count(*)over(partition by LOCATION order by SOLD_DATE range between interval'1' minute preceding and current row) cnt_preceding,
      count(*)over(partition by LOCATION order by SOLD_DATE range between current row and interval'1' minute following) cnt_following
   from car_sales
)
where 
    cnt_preceding > 1
 or cnt_following > 1
order by location, sold_date;
```

Results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=000865dd639ab8d6d6e9fbf64100fcf0

```sql
LOCATION     NUM_CARS EQUIPMEN SOLD_DATE           CNT_PRECEDING CNT_FOLLOWING
---------- ---------- -------- ------------------- ------------- -------------
coventry            1 Rovers   2019-09-07 10:00:12             1             2
coventry            2 Rovers   2019-09-07 10:00:45             2             3
coventry            3 Rovers   2019-09-07 10:01:15             2             2
coventry            3 Rovers   2019-09-07 10:01:30             3             1
leamington          7 Rovers   2019-08-30 13:10:13             1             3
leamington          3 Trans Am 2019-08-30 13:10:25             2             2
leamington          2 Trans Am 2019-08-30 13:10:48             3             1
leamington        100 Trans Am 2019-09-06 08:59:45             1             3
leamington          4 Rovers   2019-09-06 09:00:00             2             2
leamington          1 corvette 2019-09-06 09:00:10             3             1
```

So the only thing we need now is to aggregate them by non-overlapping intervals <= 1 minute. And I'll show it using another approach - MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause:

```sql
with CAR_SALES ( NUM_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, SOLD_DATE ) AS (
  SELECT   1, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:00:12' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:00:45' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:01:15' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:01:30' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   9, 'Jaguars',  'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '06:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   7, 'Rovers',   'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '13:10:13' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  10, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '09:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '13:10:48' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   8, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '18:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   4, 'Rovers',   'leamington', DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '09:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 100, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '08:59:45' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   1, 'corvette', 'leamington', DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '09:00:10' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Toyota',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '10:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  15, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '11:05:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Jaguars',  'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '17:02:07' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '13:10:25' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL
)
select *
from car_sales
match_recognize (
   partition by location
   order by sold_date
   MEASURES  
      FIRST(A.SOLD_DATE) dt_strt,
      LAST(SOLD_DATE) dt_end,
      MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno,
      CLASSIFIER() AS cls
   ALL ROWS PER MATCH
   PATTERN (A B+)
   DEFINE
      B AS B.sold_date < first(A.sold_date) + interval '1' minute
)
order by location, sold_date
;
```

Results:

```sql
LOCATION   SOLD_DATE           DT_STRT             DT_END                     MNO CLS     NUM_CARS EQUIPMEN
---------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ----- ---------- --------
coventry   2019-09-07 10:00:12 2019-09-07 10:00:12 2019-09-07 10:00:12          1 A              1 Rovers
coventry   2019-09-07 10:00:45 2019-09-07 10:00:12 2019-09-07 10:00:45          1 B              2 Rovers
coventry   2019-09-07 10:01:15 2019-09-07 10:01:15 2019-09-07 10:01:15          2 A              3 Rovers
coventry   2019-09-07 10:01:30 2019-09-07 10:01:15 2019-09-07 10:01:30          2 B              3 Rovers
leamington 2019-08-30 13:10:13 2019-08-30 13:10:13 2019-08-30 13:10:13          1 A              7 Rovers
leamington 2019-08-30 13:10:25 2019-08-30 13:10:13 2019-08-30 13:10:25          1 B              3 Trans Am
leamington 2019-08-30 13:10:48 2019-08-30 13:10:13 2019-08-30 13:10:48          1 B              2 Trans Am
leamington 2019-09-06 08:59:45 2019-09-06 08:59:45 2019-09-06 08:59:45          2 A            100 Trans Am
leamington 2019-09-06 09:00:00 2019-09-06 08:59:45 2019-09-06 09:00:00          2 B              4 Rovers
leamington 2019-09-06 09:00:10 2019-09-06 08:59:45 2019-09-06 09:00:10          2 B              1 corvette

10 rows selected.
```

As you can see MNO return MATCH_NUMBER(), ie number of the group in this location, so now we can easily aggregates these groups:

```sql
with CAR_SALES ( NUM_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, SOLD_DATE ) AS (
  SELECT   1, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:00:12' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:00:45' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:01:15' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '10:01:30' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   9, 'Jaguars',  'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '06:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   7, 'Rovers',   'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '13:10:13' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  10, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '09:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '13:10:48' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   8, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '18:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   4, 'Rovers',   'leamington', DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '09:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 100, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '08:59:45' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   1, 'corvette', 'leamington', DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '09:00:10' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Toyota',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-06' + INTERVAL '10:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  15, 'Rovers',   'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '11:05:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2, 'Jaguars',  'coventry',   DATE '2019-09-07' + INTERVAL '17:02:07' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3, 'Trans Am', 'leamington', DATE '2019-08-30' + INTERVAL '13:10:25' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL
)
,matches as (
   select *
   from car_sales
   match_recognize (
      partition by location
      order by sold_date
      MEASURES  
         FIRST(A.SOLD_DATE) dt_strt,
         LAST(SOLD_DATE) dt_end,
         MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno,
         CLASSIFIER() AS cls
      ALL ROWS PER MATCH
      PATTERN (A B+)
      DEFINE
         B AS B.sold_date < first(A.sold_date) + interval '1' minute
   )
)
select 
   location,
   mno,
   dt_strt,
   listagg(EQUIPMENT_TYPE,',')
     within group(order by sold_date) EQUIPMENT_TYPEs,
   listagg(to_char(sold_date,'hh24:mi:ss'),',')
     within group(order by sold_date) sold_dates
from matches
group by 
   location,
   mno,
   dt_strt
order by 1,2
;
```

Full test case with results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d2594a250f9adb5a9f290d7f72be2e05

```sql
LOCATION          MNO DT_STRT             EQUIPMENT_TYPES                          SOLD_DATES
---------- ---------- ------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
coventry            1 2019-09-07 10:00:12 Rovers,Rovers                            10:00:12,10:00:45
coventry            2 2019-09-07 10:01:15 Rovers,Rovers                            10:01:15,10:01:30
leamington          1 2019-08-30 13:10:13 Rovers,Trans Am,Trans Am                 13:10:13,13:10:25,13:10:48
leamington          2 2019-09-06 08:59:45 Trans Am,Rovers,corvette                 08:59:45,09:00:00,09:00:10
```

Comment: Back again, sorry for the delay. What would I do if I wanted to ensure that the sale dates were within 1 minute of each other by means of using epoch time. Convert the sale_date to epoch time and select the records where epoch sale_date within 1 minute

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LISTAGG(equipment_type,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY <sold_date_to_minute_precision>)` along with adding other (non-aggregated) columns to GROUP BY list :

```
SELECT location, TO_CHAR(sold_date,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') AS sold_date_minutes,
       LISTAGG(equipment_type,',') WITHIN GROUP 
       ( ORDER BY location, TO_DATE(sold_date,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') ) AS equipment_type
  FROM car_sales c
 GROUP BY location, TO_CHAR(sold_date,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=153992d807e815178e40183adc20ec69)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you Barbaros, I was able to get the same results in sqldeveloper.  I am not getting the rovers,rovers result that you are getting

Comment: you're welcome @Gilly ,  did you check the conversion to_timestamp with standard datetime format within the demo ?

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Error I get is:ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: directly related with the date format, please follow the date conversion within the demo @Gilly ( `timestamp'2019-09-07 10:00:12'` directly or `to_date('2019-09-07 10:00:12','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')` explicitly )

Comment: Thank you Barbaros, I get it now- sorry.  Is there a way to explicitly call the results by 60 seconds instead of using the minute.

Comment: how can the code be changed to allow for 00:00:58 and 00:01:02 as a possible result? Basically it would be perfect to go by 60 seconds instead. But how do you do that?

Comment: it's very hard to think of :) .. @Gilly consider the times within the same date 10:00:10 - 10:01:04 - 10:02:00, in which minute-wise group can we accumulate those timestamp values ...?

Comment: I see, so sticking with the minute should get the results needed.  Thank you Barbaros.

Comment: Back again, sorry for the delay.  What would I do if I wanted to ensure that the sale dates were within 1 minute of each other by means of using epoch time.  Convert the sale_date to epoch time and select the records where epoch sale_date within 1 minute

Comment: I ran some more tests and I was hoping that converting to a epoch number would ensure the result without failure.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can use the [TRUNC](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html) function to truncate the date to the minute.  You can then group by that value to find any cars that were sold within the same minute.

```
  SELECT location,
         TO_CHAR (TRUNC (sold_date, 'MI'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI PM')     AS sold_minute,
         LISTAGG (equipment_type, ',') as equipment_list
    FROM car_sales
GROUP BY location, TRUNC (sold_date, 'MI')
  HAVING COUNT (*) > 1;
```

Comment: This would not find values that were sold at `00:00:58` and `00:01:02`.

Comment: Thank you EJ, I used the following code:  SELECT location,
         TO_CHAR (TRUNC (sold_date, 'MI'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI PM')     AS sold_minute,
         LISTAGG (equipment_type, ',') within group(order by location) as equipment_list
    FROM car_sales
GROUP BY location, TRUNC (sold_date, 'MI')
  HAVING COUNT (*) > 1;

Comment: MTO: how can the code be changed to allow for 00:00:58 and 00:01:02 as a possible result? Basically it would be perfect to go by 60 seconds instead.  But how do you do that?

Comment: @Gilly - Does the actual car_sales table have a primary key?  It might be possible, but not without a primary key on the table to prevent a record from being counted twice.