# Use EPOCH time for timestamp to get records within 1 minute

Tags: oracle, timestamp, epoch

I was curious to see how in Oracle 12c you can take a timestamp datatype and convert the records into EPOCH time to make them a number and then use that number to find any records within that date column that are within 1 minute of each other (assuming the same day if needed, or simply any calculations within 1 minute).

I tried the following but got an ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small error.

select (sold_date - to_date('1970-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))*86400 as epoch_sold_date from test1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `SOLD_DATE`? For e.g. `SYSDATE` (function that returns `DATE` datatype), your code works OK.

```
SQL> select (sysdate
  2          - to_date('1970-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  3         ) * 86400 as epoch_sold_date
  4  from dual;

EPOCH_SOLD_DATE
---------------
     1600807918

SQL>
```

---

As `SOLD_DATE` is a timestamp, but - it appears that fractions of a second aren't or special interest to you, cast it to `DATE`:

```
select (cast (systimestamp as date)                                --> this
        - to_date('1970-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
       ) * 86400 as epoch_sold_date 
from dual;
```

---

Saying that you get the same result for all rows: well, I don't, and you shouldn't either if `SOLD_DATE` differs.

```
SQL> with test (sold_date) as
  2    (select timestamp '2020-09-22 00:00:00.000000' from dual union all
  3     select timestamp '2015-03-18 00:00:00.000000' from dual
  4    )
  5  select sold_date,
  6         (cast (sold_date as date)
  7          - to_date('1970-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  8         ) * 86400 as epoch_sold_date
  9  from test;

SOLD_DATE                      EPOCH_SOLD_DATE
------------------------------ ---------------
22.09.20 00:00:00,000000000         1600732800
18.03.15 00:00:00,000000000         1426636800

SQL>
```

---

One more edit: when you subtract two timestamps, result is `interval day to second`. If you extract minutes from it, you get what you wanted:

```
SQL> with test (sold_date) as
  2    (select timestamp '2020-09-22 10:15:00.000000' from dual union all
  3     select timestamp '2015-03-18 08:05:00.000000' from dual
  4    )
  5  select sold_date,
  6         lead(sold_date) over (order by sold_date) next_sold_date,
  7         --
  8         lead(sold_date) over (order by sold_date) - sold_date diff,
  9         --
 10         extract(day from lead(sold_date) over (order by sold_date) - sold_date) diff_mins
 11  from test
 12  order by sold_date;

SOLD_DATE                      NEXT_SOLD_DATE                 DIFF                            DIFF_MINS
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
18.03.15 08:05:00,000000000    22.09.20 10:15:00,000000000    +000002015 02:10:00.000000000        2015
22.09.20 10:15:00,000000000

SQL>
```

In your case, you'd check whether extracted *minutes* value is larger than `1` (minute).

---

If you just want to see how many minutes are there between two timestamps, then

- cast them to dates
- subtract those dates (and you'll get number of days)
- multiply it by 24 (as there are 24 hours in a day) and by 60 (as there are 60 minutes in an hour)

Something like this:

```
SQL> with test (date_1, date_2) as
  2    (select timestamp '2020-09-22 10:15:00.000000',
  3            timestamp '2020-09-22 08:05:00.000000' from dual
  4    )
  5  select (cast(date_1 as date) - cast(date_2 as date)) * 24 * 60 diff_minutes
  6  from test;

DIFF_MINUTES
------------
         130

SQL>
```

Comment: SOLD_DATE TIMESTAMP(6)

Comment: Sqldeveloper NLS timestamp value is yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss

Comment: Thank you Littlefoot.  How would I take these values and find resulting dates from my tables that are within 1 minute of each other as epoch time dates?

Comment: Edited it once again, as you said that you got the same result for all rows in a table. I don't.

Comment: could I use  between (cast (sold_date as date)
           - to_date('1970-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
           ) * 86400 as sold_date1 - interval '1' MINUTE
                  and (cast (sold_date as date)
            - to_date('1970-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
           ) * 86400 as sold_date2 + interval '1' MINUTE

Comment: Is it possible to use interval day to second with EPOCH time instead of timestamp?  Again I am trying to figure out if a date is within 1 minute of another date in a column, the problem I have is that interval day to second is only looking at the minute or seconds and not the year/month/day hour minute second to get the value, it appears to just examine the minute or second and not the whole date.

Comment: Yet another example :) See if it helps; looks quite simple, if it suits your needs.

Comment: Oh yes - see this page: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-dates-timestamps-and-intervals#interval . It contains many nice examples, perhaps you'll find something interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to compare dates and find rows that are within one minute of each other, you do not need to use epoch time.  There are several solutions to this problem on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63926791/oracle-select-dates-for-items-sold-within-1-minute-of-each-other/63927333).

Comment: that was my old thread, I found that it was giving me results that were not within 1 minute of each other.  I wanted to try forcing the dates into a numeric format so that the math will not fail

Comment: If the solutions on the previous thread are not working, please provide sample data to simulate the case where the previous solutions are not working.